# Installing Ubuntu to have a dualboot system running on Asus UEFI bios

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to dualboot with Ubuntu but I am facing an issue when trying to install ubuntu, for some reason the BIOS doesn't recognize the USB stick which I reformatted with Etcher. Any advice?

[Here you can see WIN recognizing the USB stick:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj6zj.png)

[And here, picture taken with the Phone it doesn't recognize it:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZXzA.jpg)

Comment: "*the BIOS doesn't recognize the USB stick*" - How did you determine this?  Did you verify the checksum/integrity of the .ISO you downloaded before flashing it to a USB?  Did you disable Fast Boot in Windows? Have you tried everything here: [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi).   Maybe also try a different USB stick and/or port.

Comment: @Nmath
Eddit is for you to see that WIN does recognize it.

Comment: So like it is being recognized on other devices as USB stick when in windows, but haven't tried to dualboot with it on other devices as that other device is company property. Also, my windows does recognize it as a device normally, however, when trying to boot from it it isnt being recognized. And no I haven't seen an option to disable/enable booting from USB. Also, how do I deactive or even check if there is a Fast Boot? I think I have seen it in the BIOS but it isn't clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Asus may be picky about recognizing USBs.  Have the USB present when you shutdown, then in BIOS/UEFI Settings, it should show up in the bootorder, and may be put first. This setting may not persist even if you just switch USBs.

---

Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO?  A bad download may prevent the USB from booting.  Does the USB work in other ports, in other machines?  Maybe there was a bad write to the USB, and it wont work anywhere.  Number of partitions on the hard disk may prevent an install, if DOS partitioning is used and all four primary partitions are used, but shouldn't affect booting the USB.

---

Setting up a bootable USB  which works for both BIOS and UEFI is dog-meat simple -- a byte-for-byte copy of the ISO to the USB is all it takes (the dd method).  You wont get any persistence, and any space on the USB over 4G will be wasted, so various programs offer ways to do that, confusing the basic issue. Additionally, about 5 years ago, the ISO added a link, which is fine for an ISO9660, but not allowed on a Fat filesystem, so just copying the files out of the ISO onto a FAT USB no longer worked (for a UEFI boot). Since the USB you made  works on other computers, you have the technique, now you just have to figure out what your Asus needs to boot, or find a Windows dd equivalent to just copy the ISO, which boots both ways.  The Rufus defaults should work, but I am not familiar with Rufus.  I do know you should avoid offers of strange filesystems like ntfs or exfat23.

Comment: I did not remove the USB stick nor change it after refactoring. I tried after a couple of times to plug it in and out to see if it would get recognized later but unfortunately that did not solve my problem either. In Windows the USB is recognized also after the refactoration. I refactored it now with 2 different softwares. Could it be related to me having 4 partitions that BIOS/UEFI recognized?

Comment: It does work on other machines, and the download seems to be fine, but I'll try it again with a different one. Downloaded it directly from ubuntu. I have several Harddisks and I did partition them in order to have ubuntu on one of them.

Comment: I used now different programms to make the USB bootable, but either I run into a command line issue so Ubuntu does not show the UI or the USB stick isn't recognized in the UEFI, I tried to do it with exFAT32 as file system and NTFS either did not help. I did not know that it is so difficult to get Ubuntu run as dualboot with win10